# toshiba satellite p850-00e bootable usb windows 10 black screen

Tags: windows-10, boot, toshiba-laptop

Question: Any suggestions how I can get my boot from my usb key on my toshiba?

PC:toshiba satellite p850-00e
USB:San disk 128 gb
Brand new solid state: King Dian 128 GB solid state

Description:
Attempting to install windows 10 on a Toshiba satellite p850-00e with a new solid state drive I just put in.

I press F12 loading, i get the boot menu. I select usb and I just get a black screen. No prompt to windows 10.

I tried the same usb on my desktop to boot from and it worked

1. boot menu option to be CSM.
2. boot priority to be top priority. Made no difference.
3. Boot speed is normal.
4. Boot security is disabled

Comment: So whats the question ?  (IE edit your post to actually ask one - I assume its something like how do I boot Windows on the Toshiba ?)

Comment: fixed. Ya how to get a usb boot to work on my toshiba.

Comment: How are you creating the USB? Using the offical windows 10 download tool?

Comment: Yes. I create a iso and then use refus to make the usb bootable. I am able boot it on my desktop from usb key. Doesn't work on the laptop.